# How to add and store view count for a page in express

Tags: express, reactjs, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I have a news website with some categories(Business, Entertainment, Sports, etc.), and in the front page, I want to display a list of a popular article from all articles in database.

In order to do this, I have to know which an article is popular or most viewed, so I need to put a view(visit) count to each article.

I am getting data of an article by calling api request with its id when an article is clicked, so does that mean that all I have to do is to count how many api calls are made for each id?

I am using react and redux in client, express in server, and postgresql with knex and bookshelf in database. 
This is my code for getting an article in express:

```
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
   Article.query({
      where: {id: req.params.id}
   }).fetch().then(article => {
      res.json(article)
   })
})
```

How can I add view or request count to this? or any other way?

Comment: since you have knex, you could issue a knex.raw updating a table which sole purpose is to count access. somethig like knex.raw("update articleview set artcount = artcount + 1 where article_id = :id",{id:req.params.id})

Comment: @Sombriks Thank you for your comment! Can you write this in the answer section with code? Should I add a row that looks like table.integer('viewCount')? and then what? sorry I am new to knex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rely on knex query builder, since Bookshelf uses it:

```
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
   Article.query({
      where: {id: req.params.id}
   }).fetch().then(article => {
      res.json(article)
   }).then(ret => {
      return knex.raw("update articleview set artcount = artcount + 1 where article_id = :id",{id:req.params.id}))
   })
})
```

All you'll need is to require() on your routers the builder the same way you require the models.

The [bookshelf docs](http://bookshelfjs.org/#installation) just fies over the query builder, but all you'll need is to expose him the same way you could expose a model (i.e. exports it) or to access it through the [bookshelf](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Bookshelf-instance-knex) mapper.

Also, if you're using [knex migrations](http://knexjs.org/#Migrations), you can require knexfile.js config file.

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work. What do you mean by the builder? is it a table that I created with using knex.schema.createTable? Can I just use increment method like this knex('articles').where(id: req.params.id).increment('viewCount', 1)?

Comment: Hi Dan, when i say "builder" i mean "knex", since it's a query builder. the sample i provided is just an example built based on the code you already provided. That said, articleview is a table which stores the article id and the viewcount, which i named as "artcount". How you will call this table however is up to you. Also, i've looked at the http://knexjs.org docs and there is no ".increment()" method, so the ".raw()" method will serve you well. if any doubl is left, provide me a github sample repo and i'll PR some example.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand what you were saying, but I found this: [increment method](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-increment).